# Execute params with doctrine using named parameters

Tags: php, doctrine, named-parameters

I'm encountering a strange problem with doctrine and named parameters.

Here is a query which actually works perfectly with this set of parameters (dynamic in my code):

```
$params = array(    ':id_editeur' => 1,
                    ':nom_editeur' => 'Test');

public function updateById($params)
{
    Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->update('Editeur e')
       ->set('e.nom_editeur', ':nom_editeur')
       ->where('e.id_editeur = :id_editeur')
       ->execute($params);
}
```

Now i have another function

```
public function findAll($params)
{
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Editeur e')
        ->orderBy(':orderby')
        ->limit(':limit')
        ->offset(':offset');

    return $query->execute($params);
}
```

With these parameters:

```
    $params = array(    ':orderby' => ('e.id_editeur ASC'),
                        ':limit' => (10),
                        ':offset' => (20));
```

And even if it's the same mechanism i get the following error

> Invalid parameter number: number of
>   bound variables does not match number
>   of tokens

Any idea of the reason? By the way, it works if I fill the orderby, limit and offset directly in the function in the classical way.

Comment: I had a $q->set("next_id", "?", $new_id); giving the same error message with $new_id being null. Hum... I don't know if this will help :o

Answer (score 3):

The params var cannot contain ":" character...

Try replacing:

```
$params = array(    ':id_editeur' => 1,
                ':nom_editeur' => 'Test');
```

to:

```
$params = array(    'id_editeur' => 1,
                'nom_editeur' => 'Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the parenthesis in params array.

```
$params = array(    ':orderby' => 'e.id_editeur ASC',
                    ':limit' => '10',
                    ':offset' => '20');
```

Comment: Hey, I don't know why I added them in the first time, but unfortunately no difference without it.

Comment: Strange..
Try to invoke getSqlQuery() on query object before query execution.

Comment: Yep it's kinda strange, when I echo getSqlQuery() I get
SELECT e.id_editeur AS e__id_editeur, e.nom_editeur AS e__nom_editeur FROM editeurs e ORDER BY :orderby

Comment: Which Doctrine Version do you use?

Comment: I'm using doctrine 1.2.4, i found a way to do it but I don't like it

public function findAll($params)
{
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Editeur e')
        ->orderBy($params[':orderby'])
        ->limit($params[':limit'])
        ->offset($params[':offset']);

    return $query->execute($params);
}

Comment: Sorry for the syntax in the comment above, I can manage to execute the query by passing the right $params['xx'] in each clause. But it's not what I originally wanted

Comment: Would you recommend to migrate on Doctrine 2?

Comment: I use Doctrine 2.0 without problems, but if you have an extended application, it will be a little hard to upgrade.
what   print_r($query->getParams());  returns?

Comment: It returns `I get SELECT e.id_editeur AS e__id_editeur, e.nom_editeur AS e__nom_editeur FROM editeurs e ORDER BY :orderby`